# Cant include queue/stack C++ STL classes in Netbeans IDE 7.2

Tags: c++, queue

Im implementing music project using Netbeans 7.2 IDE in C++ that involves processing sonic information. I want to use the STL queue and stack classes to process chord structures. My problem is that the IDE is not recognizing either std::queue or std::stack classes and I'm getting the dreaded red exclamation mark next to them.  I can't see how I can make further progress without these classes. Here's my code. Thanks in advance..

```
#ifndef CHORD_H
#define CHORD_H
#include "../tonestatdynlib/name_pitchstructure.h"


class chord {
public:
    chord(int chordNum);
    chord (int chordNum, bool stability);
    chord(const chord& orig); //copy constructor for use in generative procedure
    std::queue<pitchStats> _constituents;
    std::string flatPitchList(); //returns a flat pitchname list from chord members

    virtual ~chord();

private:

    int _chordNumber;
    bool _stable;//unless switched otherwise
  };
#endif /* CHORD_H */
```

Comment: Well, have you tried adding #include <deque> and #include <stack> at the top of your file?

Comment: [This documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) tells you which header you need to include.

Comment: Thx to everybody who answered my question but as I say, I've done the # include <stack> and #include <queue> but already to no avail. It's a mystery!...

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
 #include<queue>
 #include<stack>
```

to be able to use std::queue and std::stack

Comment: Thx Moritz but I've already tried belt and braces and used #includes for both stack and queue and it doesn't make any difference. PS This is a dynlib I'm making should have said so in my original question. THx for the reply tho'.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the headers for these classes.

```
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
```